# AngularJs directive, scope with value and function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive `myEditable` that toggle a `<div>` with an `<input type=text>` to allow inline edition :

```
<my-editable value="vm.contact.name"></my-editable>
```

I was happy with it until I read some articles that say that `$scope.$apply` should not be used. I'm using it when the user save his changes to update the model (`vm.contact.name` in my case) :

```
function save() {
  scope.$apply(function(){
    scope.value = editor.find('input').val();
  });
  toggle();
}
```

But since it is a bad thing, I would like to pass a callback method to my directive. This callback must be called with the new value when the user save his changes. However, it seems that I cannot add two fields to the directive scope :

```
return {
  restrict: 'EA',
  scope: {
    value: '=value'/*,
    onSave: '&onSave'*/
  },
  link: function(scope, element, attr) {
    // ...
    element.find('.save').click(function(){
      save();
    });

    // Declaration of `save` as above.
  }
}
```

If I uncomment `onSave` then the value is never received and `onSave` is undefined.

My question is, how can I give a value and a callback method to a directive ?
And, as bonus, how can I pass parameters to the callback ?

Thanks

Comment: Where is your save() function called ?

Comment: @Lorenzo, into the `link`. I have a JQuery click handler on a button or _Enter_ key to call `save`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass 'n' number of fields in directives isolated scope.

If you want to pass a function use `&`. Keep this in mind if your property name is `onSave` then in the view use it like this `on-save`.

Your directive should look like below

```
app.directive('dir',function(){
  return {
  restrict: 'EA',
  scope: {

    onSave: '&'
  },
  link: function(scope, element, attr) {
    // ...
    debugger
    console.log(scope.onSave)
    scope.onSave();

    // Declaration of `save` as above.
  }
}

})
```

In the view you can pass the function like below

```
 <dir on-Save='abc()'/>
```

OR

```
 <dir on-save='abc()'/>
```

Comment: Ok, then I will be doing something wrong. I have `scope: { value: '=value', callback: '&onSave'}` but `console.log(scope.callback)` write `function (locals) { return parentGet(scope, locals); }` with `<my-editable value="vm.item.name" on-save="vm.rename(name)"></my-editable>` on any other expression for `on-save`.

Comment: check my post I have edited it with example of how to pass a function in a directive

Comment: Yes thanks, it works. However now, the model is not refreshed automatically bu AngularsJs (view does not update), I have to do an explicit call to `$scope.$apply`.